# How to list AlbumArt from MediaLibrary on WP?

Tags: windows-phone, audio-player

I've been looking for a long time how to list album cover from Windows Phone Media Library, but I didn't found any answer.

I'm developping a music player for wp8, and actually I can successfully list album info as album name, artist name, duration, etc, but I can't get the AlbumArt.

Here is the code I'm actually using :

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="AlbumInfoTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source=" " Margin="5" Height="80" Width="80" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black"/>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Artist}" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.75"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <phone:LongListSelector
                        x:Name="llsAlbums"
                        SelectionChanged="llsAlbums_SelectionChanged"
                        Margin="0,-35,0,0"
                        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpListStyle}"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AlbumInfoTemplate}"
                        LayoutMode="List"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                        HideEmptyGroups ="true"/>
```

Hope you could help me guys !

Answer (score 0):

Before anything you need to do a small modification to the `LongListSelector` definition in XAML. Add this `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to it. Then is should look like this.

```
<phone:LongListSelector
                        x:Name="llsAlbums"
                        SelectionChanged="llsAlbums_SelectionChanged"
                        Margin="0,-35,0,0"
                        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpListStyle}"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AlbumInfoTemplate}"
                        LayoutMode="List"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                        HideEmptyGroups ="true"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Since you are using `JumpLists` and `GroupHeaders` in the `LongListSelector`, you need to to more work than usual. Start off with creating a class to hold the Album information. Lets call it `MusicAlbum` Its like this.

```
public class MusicAlbum
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Art { get; set; }
}
```

Then create this class and methods included for the GroupHeaders and JumpLists to work.

```
public class AlphaKeyGroup<T> : List<T>
{
    public delegate string GetKeyDelegate(T item);
    public string Key { get; private set; }

    public AlphaKeyGroup(string key)
    {
         Key = key;
    }

    private static List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(SortedLocaleGrouping slg)
    {
         List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> list = new List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>>();

         foreach (string key in slg.GroupDisplayNames)
         {
             list.Add(new AlphaKeyGroup<T>(key));
         }

         return list;
    }

    public static List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(IEnumerable<T> items, CultureInfo ci, GetKeyDelegate getKey, bool sort)
    {
         SortedLocaleGrouping slg = new SortedLocaleGrouping(ci);
         List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> list = CreateGroups(slg);

         foreach (T item in items)
         {
              int index = 0;
              index = slg.GetGroupIndex(getKey(item));
              if (index >= 0 && index < list.Count)
              {
                   list[index].Add(item);
              }
         }

         if (sort)
         {
              foreach (AlphaKeyGroup<T> group in list)
              {
                   group.Sort((c0, c1) => { return ci.CompareInfo.Compare(getKey(c0), getKey(c1)); });
              }
         }

         return list;
     }
}
```

Here i have written a small method to get the Album Art for the album, this makes it easy.

```
private BitmapImage GetAlbumArt(Album album)
{
     BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
     img.DecodePixelHeight = 80;
     img.DecodePixelWidth = 80;
     img.SetSource(album.GetAlbumArt());
     return img;
}
```

Then this actual methods gets the list of albums from the `MediaLibrary` and makes a list of `MusicAlbums` we can use in the LLS

```
public List<MusicAlbum> GetAlbums()
{
     if (lib == null)
         lib = new MediaLibrary();

     List<MusicAlbum> albumList = new List<MusicAlbum>();
     var albums = lib.Albums;

     foreach (var album in albums)
     {
         albumList.Add(new MusicAlbum()
         {
             Name = album.Name,
             Artist = album.Artist.Name,
             Art = album.HasArt ? GetAlbumArt(album) : null
         });
     }

     return albumList;
}
```

After doing this, you need to make the list and set the `ItemSource` of the `LongListSelector`. In the Constructor  of the page or in `OnNavigatedTo` method add this code.

```
List<AlphaKeyGroup<MusicAlbum>> albumList = AlphaKeyGroup<MusicAlbum>.CreateGroups(this.GetAlbums() as List<MusicAlbum>, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, (MusicAlbum s) => { return s.Name; }, true);
llsAlbums.ItemsSource = albumList;
```

Then you are done, run the app and you will see the albums listed..